# Unable to connect to Remote Oracle Database using Python script

Tags: python, oracle

I am unable to connect to the remote Oracle DB using python script. I am writing the below code to my script, and facing the error as below:

I have checked the following checkpoints as below:
1. Version of Python and Oracle client is same i.e. 64 bit
2. cx_Oracle module installation
3. I have downloaded ODPI-C but I don't know what to do with it.

I am using MAC OSX.

Code:

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns=cx_Oracle.makedsn('dbpx87mp.co.zing.com','1901','bpx87mp')
conn=cx_Oracle.connect('admin','Password',dsn_tns)
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from <table_name>")
for line in cur:
    print(line)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/558220/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.2/scratches/oraScript.py", line 6, in <module>

conn=cx_Oracle.connect('admin','Password',dsn_tns)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
```

Comment: how did you install the oracle python module ?

Comment: "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library" where is oracle client software?

Comment: @rednaks I installed the Oracle Python module through PyCharm IDE.

Comment: @Needlefile Could you please let me know if you are looking for DB location? If it is DB location, then it is a remote server. I am using Oracle SQL Developer to access it using the hostname, userID and password.

Comment: directly in u error message https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos  follow intructions

Comment: @Needlefile I did the same but was unable to make any progress.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can't use the default system Python with cx_Oracle because this Python has restricted entitlements and will fail to load Oracle client libraries.

Use Python via something like homebrew or install Python yourself. See the cx_Oracle installation instructions https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-macos